# Making the original linked excutable directory accessible

Tags: python-3.x, linux, bash

I have a python script `program.py` and I wanted to have access to it everywhere in the system. Therefore, I used `chmod +x` and used a hard link to put it in the `/somewhere/bin/`.

This successfully made the `program.py` executable anywhere, but at the same time I lost access to the original directory where the program resides `/original/dir/program.py`.

There is a configuration file in the original directory, in a folder: `/original/dir/configurations/cfg.txt` and I want to also access it everywhere in the system, example: `program.py configurations/cfg.txt`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with a hard link (because a hard link is indistinguishable from any other hard link of the same file, including the original name; for all practical purposes, it *is* an "original" name), but if you use a symlink, you can drill through it to find the real directory [with `os.path.realpath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.realpath).

```
from os.path import dirname, join, realpath

realdir = dirname(realpath(__file__))
cfgfile = join(realdir, 'configurations', 'cfg.txt')
```

or [with `pathlib`, using `Path.resolve` for similar effect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.resolve):

```
from pathlib import Path

realdir = Path(__file__).resolve().parent
cfgfile = realdir / 'configurations' / 'cfg.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems kind of overkill to need to access the folder anywhere in the system. Why not just have the user provide the command-line argument of the configuration they want (e.g. `python program.py cfg1.txt`) and then have some basic logic in the program to get the file:

```py
import os
cfgArg = # string command line argument
cfgPath = os.path.join('configurations', cfgArg)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood your requirements you have a python prog with specific config in a folder and you need.

- Not move the file to other folder
- Script needs access to config.

Good I think you can make a softlink to /usr/bin or whatever folder be in your $PATH, so you do not move the original file and you can execute it system wide.

```
ln -s origin destination
```

so

```
ln -s /original/dir/program.py /usr/bin/program.py
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use .bashrc to change your path and add this line in your .bahrc file:

export PATH=$PATH:/original/dir:/original/dir/configurations